# dynamic created controls in page_init and accessing in click event

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have created a dynamic table in `page_Init` event. How can I access that table in click event  handler? Currently it is not accessible in click event handler. Actually I need to traverse the dynamic created table for other dynamic controls which have been added in that table.

Comment: You need to show some code and also tell us what you've tried already

Answer (score 0):

Declare private local variables in your Page, like `_table As...`.

Then, in Page_Init, use those variables `_table = New...`.

You will be able to use `_table` later in the Page Life Cycle.